# Sort user input alphabetically with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-orderby

I have built a simple Bootstrap-based form. The collected user input are displayed at the bottom of the page (thanks to AngularJS):

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<body ng-app>
<form>
  <fieldset class="border rounded">
  <legend class="alert alert-info">Keywords</legend>
    <div class="form-group row" id="IT-keywords">
      <label for="keywordsIT" class="col-auto col-form-label">Five <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">Italian</span> keywords:</label>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keywordsIT" id="keywordsIT1" ng-model="keywordsIT1">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keywordsIT" id="keywordsIT2" ng-model="keywordsIT2">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keywordsIT" id="keywordsIT3" ng-model="keywordsIT3">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keywordsIT" id="keywordsIT4" ng-model="keywordsIT4">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keywordsIT" id="keywordsIT5" ng-model="keywordsIT5">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row" id="EN-keywords">
      <label for="keywordsEN" class="col-auto col-form-label">Five <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">English</span> keywords:</label>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keywordsEN" id="keywordsEN1" ng-model="keywordsEN1">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keywordsEN" id="keywordsEN2" ng-model="keywordsEN2">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keywordsEN" id="keywordsEN3" ng-model="keywordsEN3">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keywordsEN" id="keywordsEN4" ng-model="keywordsEN4">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keywordsEN" id="keywordsEN5" ng-model="keywordsEN5">
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<p>My five Italian keywords: {{keywordsIT1}}, {{keywordsIT2}}, {{keywordsIT3}}, {{keywordsIT4}}, {{keywordsIT5}}.</p>
<p>My five English keywords: {{keywordsEN1}}, {{keywordsEN2}}, {{keywordsEN3}}, {{keywordsEN4}}, {{keywordsEN5}}.</p>
</body>
```

I was wondering whether it would be possible to sort alphabetically the list of keywords **after** the user has typed them, so that if:

- `{{keywordsEN1}} = b`, `{{keywordsEN2}} = d`, `{{keywordsEN3}} = a`,
  `{{keywordsEN4}} = e`, `{{keywordsEN5}} = c`

the result is:

- `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use arrays instead as they are easier to handle. This way all you need to do is `sort` the array and then `join` the elements in the array with a `,`. I'm using `filter` to filter out all the `null` or `undefined` values before sorting so that they are omitted. Use `localeCompare` and convert your strings to lowercase during `sort` so that it will work correctly even if there are capital letters in your input.

Also, since Italian words contain accents/diacritics (Eg. `è` or `ò`), you will need to normalize the input before you sort the array.

Here is a working example.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', ['$scope', ($scope) => {
    $scope.keywordsIT = new Array(5);
    $scope.keywordsEN = new Array(5);

    $scope.sortKeywordsIT = function() {
      return $scope.keywordsIT
        .filter(keyword => !!keyword)
        .map(keyword => keyword.normalize("NFD"))
        .sort((k1, k2) => k1.toLowerCase().localeCompare(k2.toLowerCase()))
        .join(', ');
    }

    $scope.sortKeywordsEN = function() {
      return $scope.keywordsEN
        .filter(keyword => !!keyword)
        .sort((k1, k2) => k1.toLowerCase().localeCompare(k2.toLowerCase()))
        .join(', ');
    }
  }]);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <form>
    <fieldset class="border rounded">
      <legend class="alert alert-info">Keywords</legend>
      <div class="form-group row" id="IT-keywords">
        <label for="keywordsIT" class="col-auto col-form-label">Five <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">Italian</span> keywords:</label>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keywordsIT" id="keywordsIT1" ng-model="keywordsIT[0]">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keywordsIT" id="keywordsIT2" ng-model="keywordsIT[1]">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keywordsIT" id="keywordsIT3" ng-model="keywordsIT[2]">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keywordsIT" id="keywordsIT4" ng-model="keywordsIT[3]">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keywordsIT" id="keywordsIT5" ng-model="keywordsIT[4]">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row" id="EN-keywords">
        <label for="keywordsEN" class="col-auto col-form-label">Five <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">English</span> keywords:</label>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keywordsEN" id="keywordsEN1" ng-model="keywordsEN[0]">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keywordsEN" id="keywordsEN2" ng-model="keywordsEN[1]">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keywordsEN" id="keywordsEN3" ng-model="keywordsEN[2]">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keywordsEN" id="keywordsEN4" ng-model="keywordsEN[3]">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keywordsEN" id="keywordsEN5" ng-model="keywordsEN[4]">
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <p>My five Italian keywords: {{sortKeywordsIT()}}.</p>
  <p>My five English keywords: {{sortKeywordsEN()}}.</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @nash11! Your solution works quite well, but the downside of this approach is that `.sort()` method is case-sensitive. So if you type:   `{{keywordsEN1}} = New York`, `{{keywordsEN2}} = city`, `{{keywordsEN3}} = town`, `{{keywordsEN4}} = United States`, `{{keywordsEN5}} = America`  the result will be: `America`, `New York`, `United States`, `city`, `town`. What about injecting a `orderBy` filter [inside the controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy#using-orderby-inside-a-controller) instead? I can't manage to modify your code correctly by my own...

Comment: @Gianluca - I have edited my answer so that the sorting works by converting the strings to lowercase before comparing them. This should work for you :)

Comment: Now it works like a charm, thank you! :-)  
Just for the record, I eventually managed to modify your very first code using the `orderBy` method; I'm not sure it is "clean" from a stylistic point of view, but... it works as well!  ;-)

Comment: ```angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', ['$scope', 'orderByFilter', function($scope, orderBy) {
    $scope.keywordsIT = new Array(5);
    $scope.keywordsEN = new Array(5);

    $scope.sortKeywordsIT = function() {
      return orderBy($scope.keywordsIT).filter(keyword => !!keyword).map(keyword => keyword.normalize("NFD")).join(', ');
    }

    $scope.sortKeywordsEN = function() {
      return orderBy($scope.keywordsEN).filter(keyword => !!keyword).map(keyword => keyword).join(', ');
    }
  }]);
```

Comment: @Gianluca - although that might work for English, for Italian, if you use accents (eg. `à`), it will not sort properly with the code you provided using `orderBy` :)

Comment: You're absolutely right: I am very grateful for your help and your kind explanations! :-)